# Change background color on Android Listview Item in non touch mode

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem

I have a listview that is populated using custom ArrayAdapter. On the ListView, I run an Async task to scroll to a positon using

```
  getListView().setSelection(position);
```

I want to be able to highlight the selected item with a different background color.  The problem is that the the background color is not changing on selected items because it is in non touch mode. It works fine in touch mode.  On my XML I have already used the following but the color doesn't change

```
 android:state_selected="true" 
 android:drawable="@color/blue" />
```

Comment: Why can't you use touch mode and don't override onclickitemlistner for listview?

Comment: I'm using the listview for read only purpose. It will automatically scroll based on an audio file playing in the background. The listview items have English translation to the audio, hence need period scrolling in non touch mode.

Comment: get the selected child view using listView.getChildAt(position) and try changing the background

Comment: Thanks. I did that...but it is adding background to multiple items as the list scrolls. I event tried to specify just one  list item like so but it is highlighting multiple lines.  getListView().getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

Comment: you should return different view types for higlighted view and normal view  in getviewtype() function in adapter and change the view background accordingly in getview() function